# Store the "call"-function of a function in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, call, prototype

why does the following not work as expected ?

```
> function Double() { return this * 2; }
undefined
> Double
[Function: Double]
> Double.call
[Function: call]
> Double.call(8)
16
> var double = Double.call;
undefined
> double
[Function: call]
> double(8); ////// BAM! Why does this not work ??
TypeError: object is not a function
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:129:27)
    at bound (domain.js:271:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:284:12)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:277:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:101:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:194:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:523:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:798:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:98:10)
>
```

*** EDIT ***

I've created a function ref() to achieve this:

```
Function.prototype.ref = function() {
    var that = this;
    return function(thisArg, args) {
        return that.call(thisArg, args);
    };
}
```

Now Double.ref() is a passable function where the first argument is this.

Comment: Why not simply give `Double` a parameter instead of using `this`?

Comment: `var double = Function.call.bind(Double)`

Comment: You can bind the context: `var double = Double.call.bind(Double); double(8);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you do this:

```
var double = Double.call;
```

You lose the context of `Double`. So then when you invoke `double` it expects a context of a function (since that's what `Function.prototype.call` requires) and doesn't find it.

To try and put it more simply, you're trying to invoke `Function.prototype.call` on something that isn't a function.

You could make it work by binding the reference to `Double.call` back to `Double`:

```
var double = Double.call.bind(Double);
double(8); // 16
```

And just to further demonstrate what's happening, you can use any reference to `Function.prototype.call`, not just the one you got via `Double`:

```
var double = Function.prototype.call.bind(Double);
double(8); // 16
```